# bash split csv file and output same extension and remove last empty line

Tags: bash, csv, unix, split

I have the following input file:

```
srcfile.csv
```

which looks like:

```
3.8,1.9,1000
3.8,2,1000
3.8,2.1,1000
3.8,2.2,1000
3.8,2.3,1000
3.8,2.4,1000
3.8,2.5,1000
3.8,2.6,1000
3.8,2.7,1000
3.8,2.8,1000
3.8,2.9,1000
3.8,3,1000
3.8,3.1,1000
```

I am splitting it into files of equal number of lines:

```
split -l 20 -d srcfile.csv outputFile_
```

the resulting files don't have csv extension and they have an extra empty line at the end of the each output file.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you put in an example section of the file, the expected output and what you've tried to do to fix it already?

Comment: @theWanderer4865 no need for the expected output, it is extremely obvious! i have already shared what i have tried! if i knew the answer, why should i have posted here??

Comment: I tried `split -l 5 -d srcfile.csv outputFile_` on your sample with `split (GNU coreutils) 8.25`, no empty line at end of each output.. what's your version?

Comment: @Sundeep mine is split (GNU coreutils) 8.25 , as well

Comment: @Sundeep i found why i have "extra lines" it is because i am opening it with sublime text, i opened with gedit, and it was ok. so i accept the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the additional suffix flag:

```
   --additional-suffix=SUFFIX
          append an additional SUFFIX to file names
```

Like so:

```
split -l 20 --additional-suffix='.csv' -d srcfile.csv outputFile_
```

Comment: actually there is typo, it should be **additional**, but how to remove those extra empty lines?

Comment: Hmm, I don't actually see empty lines at the end of any of the files that I generated... But you could `for x in outputFile_*; do head -n -1 $x > $x; done` - and that will shave off the last line, but I don't think I would do that... I think I would just live with the empty line, or otherwise make sure your source file doesn't have those - there's got to be some other cause..

Comment: i found why i have "extra lines" it is because i am opening it with sublime text, i opened with gedit, and it was ok. so i accept the answer